# Error when viewing database mirroring monitor in SQL Server with non-default port

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, port, sql, mirroring

I have database mirroring set up (with witness) on SQL Server 2014 Standard. Both servers use default instance on a non-default port (not 1433).
Mirroring works perfectly fine. However, when I try to use the Database Mirroring Monitor I cannot connect to the mirror (continually switches between "waiting for data" and "not connected to [Server Name]).

Steps taken:

- Under Manage Server Instance Connections, I have tried to use SQL Authentication (this is correct as I am not using windows auth).
  Error: 
  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
- Under Manage Server Instance Connections, I have tried to Add a new connection. Receive same error as above.
- Specified with IP address.
  Error:
  SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, '[Server name]'. (Replication.Utilities)
- Specified server name with ",port" as non-default port, same error.

Notes - I can connect in SSMS with the conenction string ([Server Name],[port]), and I can ping the [Server Name] successfully. I have also tried creating an Alias in Config manager, but cannot use this either (same error about actual server name).

In summary - it seems it tries to connect with default port (and fails), but then will not let me specify a non-default port.

Has anyone successfully set up  database mirroring monitor with non-default port?

Comment: Is your SQL Server Browser running on both ends?

Comment: As there is only the single default instance, SQL Browser is not running. I tried all the same processes with Browser started - but no luck....